# how to read xml data from a column of MS Access File

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ms access file in which one of the columns have xml tagged data. The database columns and sample data are in image

[image: Sample database file]

What is the better way to read column **AppliesTo** from an Access File.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to connect to a database, or that you don't know how to read XML in .NET? Both are fairly simple and well-documented on MSDN (and on Stack Overflow, for that matter).

Comment: There is no special xml data type in MS Access, so you can read this content as a regular string.
Then this string should be converted to xml - that's the separate topic not related to MS Access

Comment: So qasali, you're saying you're already able to connect to the Access database using C#, but you're not sure how to treat that data as XML?

Comment: @Brian: Yes. An efficient way to parse XML data

Comment: Have a look at System.Xml.XmlDocument on MSDN. It's pretty straightforward.